# Combine two variables

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables

How can i combine this:

```
 var vlakh2 = $(".header .text h2").height();
 var vlakp = $(".header p:first").height();
 var vlak = vlak2 + vlakp;
```

Thanks!!!

Comment: Exactly like this... depending on what you understand by *combine*. What is the result you get and what do you want to get?

Comment: Cast the values to int and you should be fine! var vlakp = parseInt($(".header").height());

Comment: @Baszz: `(int)` is not JavaScript and `height` already returns a number.

Comment: You should use parseInt() instead of (int).....this should work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to have a typo.

In your code, you declare `vlakh2` but use `vlak2`.

Try it like this...

```
var vlakh2 = $(".header .text h2").height();    
var vlakp = $(".header p:first").height();    
var vlak = vlakh2 + vlakp;
```

Also, if the typo is not actually in your code, casting to a number may solve the issue. But it should work without needing to do this (an example for future use perhaps)

```
var vlak = Number(vlakh2) + Number(vlakp);
```

Comment: oooh god. I am not see that haha. But can i combine vlakh2 and vlakp?

Comment: Again: What do you mean by *combine*? Concatenation? Addition? Anything else?

Answer (score 2):

I think you have a typo.. Works for me at [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/konnwat/CG6ft/1/)

```
var vlakh2 = $(".header .text h2").height();
var vlakp = $(".header p:first").height();
var vlak = vlakh2 + vlakp;
alert(vlak);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var vlakh2 = $(".header .text h2").height();
var vlakp = $(".header p:first").height();
var vlak = parseInt(vlakh2) + parseInt(vlakp);
```

Also use `parseInt` to ensure the 2 variables are numeric. This will add the 2 numbers together

Comment: yes you are right - but for completeness i have added parseInt - i think the problem was the typo

Answer (score 0):

what do you mean by combining ?? concat or add ??

to add ,simply parseInt the values before adding

```
a = parseInt($("...").height(), 10);
b = parseInt($("...").height(), 10);
c = a + b;
```